# How to assign a "Bank Transaction" from a bank feed to an "Invoice" using Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I'm developing a Xero integration for a client. We have a registration/membership system for customers, and we want to integrate this with Xero in order to detect payments and close the loop.

It will look something like this:

1. Our system will create and update contacts in Xero for members;
2. Our system will create invoices in Xero for their recurring payments according to their memberships;
3. Xero will load bank transactions automatically via bank feed;
4. *Our system will implement some custom logic to link bank transactions against customer invoices*;
5. Our system will query Xero to determine if a customer has an overdue balance, and enable or restrict their membership accordingly.

It is step 4 that is the topic of my question.

---

#### How to match a `Bank Transaction` to an `Invoice` via the API?

We want to make the entire process "hands off" for the accounting team, only requiring intervention via the Xero app in exceptional cases.

Membership payments will most likely not contain any references to the invoice, number they will reference a "membership number" from our external system, so it would be impossible for Xero to automatically match transactions from the bank feed against an invoice.

Hence I want our external system to periodically pull in bank transactions via the API, and use it's own logic to allocate them as payments against Xero the appropriate invoices, in order for customer balances to be correct. How can I do this?

It seems like "Bank Transactions" (automatically created by Xero from the bank feed) are completely different entities from "Payments" against invoices (different API endpoints). Would I need to delete the transaction, and then create a payment with the same info?

Or is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more experimentation, it seems that bank transactions imported from bank statements (and I assume those imported via direct bank feed also) do not actually appear in the Xero API as `BankTransaction`s or otherwise until they have been manually reconciled via the Xero API.

When they are manually reconciled, they are created in Xero as either a `Payment` or a `BankTransaction` etc, depending how the user reconciled it.

In this was it seems utterly impossible to implement some sort of automated reconciliation app at this stage...

Would appreciate some confirmation or input from someone who knows Xero better than I do...

Comment: See here, why reconciliation via the API is not supported
https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api/suggestions/2884040-reconcile-via-the-api

Comment: Totally ridiculous that Xero hasn't sorted this yet. The last comment from Xero was on  May 29, 2018 and as it has been marked as declined, you can't vote on it. It definitely needs to be revisited.